# Check an integer in range as prolog with state transition

Tags: prolog

I would like to check if an integer is within a range in Prolog, as in this question: [Prolog: Check if X is in range of 0 to K - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292128/prolog-check-if-x-is-in-range-of-0-to-k-1) However, I would like to be able to reason about the range.  This code works:

```
check_age(X, Mn, Mx)  :-
   X >= Mn,
   X <= Mx.
```

so that `check_age(5, 3,8).` responds correctly.  I would like to be able to do

```
check_age(5, Y, 8).
```

and have it return `Y=5`.  That is, determine what `Mn` should be to make it true.  I am currently using swi-prolog.

Comment: `X <= Mx` does not work, it would be `X =< Mx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLPFD will do it, but it will tell you that `Y in inf..5` because it's also true if Y=4; Y=3; Y=2; ... negative infinity.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

n_min_max(N, Min, Max) :-
    (Min #=< N), (N #< Max).

?- n_min_max(5, Y, 8).
Y in inf..5
```

You would need to *label* Y, and choose some limits for it, and perhaps tune the CLPFD search strategy so that Min takes the biggest possible value and Max takes the smallest possible value:

```
?- n_min_max(5, Y, Z),
   [Y, Z] ins 0..100,
   labeling([max(Y), min(Z)], [Y,Z]).

Y = 5,
Z = 6 ;

Y = 5,
Z = 7 ;

Y = 5,
Z = 8 ;
```

That will change your approach to the code in ways that might be annoying.

Otherwise, an ugly chain of if/else checking what is grounded (which variables have values and which don't):

```
n_min_max(N, Min, Max) :-
    ((ground(Min), ground(Max))
    -> (Min =< N, N < Max)
    ;  ((ground(N), ground(Min))
       -> N = Max
       ; ((ground(N), ground(Max))
         ->   N = Min
         ; (ground(N)
           ->  (N = Min, N=Max)
           ; false)))).
```

e.g.

```
?- n_min_max(5, 3, 8).
true

?- n_min_max(5, Y, 8).
Y = 5

?- n_min_max(5, 3, Z).
Z = 5

?- n_min_max(5, Y, Z).
Y = Z, Z = 5
```

and you could change the third line to use `between/3` to generate possibles for X on backtracking, nb. between/3 includes the top value of the range

```
    -> (succ(RangeMax, Max), between(Min,RangeMax,N))
```

with that change:

```
?- n_min_max(X, 5, 8).
X = 5 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 7
```